# Solr MoreLikeThis example 404 error

Tags: solr, morelikethis, mlt

I'm trying to test the mlt example in **solr 6** by executing the "techproducts" example bundled in the version. It's OK and I saw data etc. nevertheless, I get **404 error** when I try to use **mlt** features (ie: http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?q=id:UTF8TEST&mlt.fl=manu,cat&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.mintf=1).

Should I configure some parameters in solr.xml or other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="df">your_default_search_field</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```